# "Classical" bicartesian closed category?

Tags: logic, category-theory, categorical-logic

Every Heyting algebra can be thought of as a bicartesian closed category through which is also a poset.

We may interpret classical logic in a Heyting algebra if we ask of their pseudocomplements to be complements, i.e: to be boolean.

Can we give a similar definition with bicartesian closed categories in general and not get a preorder? That is, a "boolean bicartesian closed category".

Intuitively I'd say you can't but who knows.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking? Heyting algebras are special cases of bicartesian closed categories: you don't need to take any quotients.

Comment: @RobArthan Indeed, it's a bit confusing in retrospect how I wrote it. Editing. It is true that Heyting algebras are bicartesian closed categories which are posets. I meant that given any bicartesian closed category, if you do these two quotients you get a Heyting algebra.

Comment: @RobArthan the question is if we can have a "fat" interpretation of classical logic, in the sense that you can have more than one morphism between two objects.

Comment: What does it mean, in your terms, for an arbitrary (non-thin) bicartesian category to be classical/Boolean?

Comment: @Z.A.K thanks for the comment. The question is precisely if this could be defined so that it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define Boolean bicartesian closed categories : for each object $A$, the canonical morphism from A to its bidual is an isomorphism. Then we can prove that such categories are necessarily thin.

If you accept the product not to be Cartesian, then you can consider [star-autonomous categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/star-autonomous+category#:%7E:text=There%20are%20many%20ways%20to,product%20in%20a%20particular%20way.): there are such categories that are not thin.

Answer (score 1):

No, not in the manner you suggest. The "collapse" starts to happen the moment you allow initial objects and the exponential (and the product) to come together. That's for *Cartesian closed categories*. It doesn't matter whether it's bi-Cartesian or not.

I showed, in some detail, where and how the cascade of collapses happen here [Decidability of bi-cartesian closed categories](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4032422/decidability-of-bi-cartesian-closed-categories).

All of the "negative" formulae - those expressible as $¬A$, a.k.a. "regular" formulae - fall into a boolean lattice, where negation is defined by $¬A = A ⊃ ⊥$, and $⊥$ corresponds to the *initial object*. More generally and more precisely, the unique morphism $f: A → ¬B$ that witnesses the conditional $A ⊃ ¬B$ is given by $f = ⋀{([]_{A∧B})}^{-1}$, using the notation in the linked reply. This is true regardless of whether $A$ is negative or not.

The linked reply shows that if $g: A∧B → ⊥$, then $g = ([]_{A∧B})^{-1}$, where $[]_{A∧B}: ⊥ → A∧B$ is the unique morphism that witnesses the conditinal $⊥ ⊃ A∧B$. Under the "Curry" operator $⋀$, this becomes $⋀g: A → B ⊃ ⊥$. Conversely, if $f: A → ¬B = B ⊃ ⊥$, then $⋁f: A∧B → ⊥$, where $⋁$ is the inverse of the Curry operator, and uniqueness then gives us $⋁f = ([]_{A∧B})^{-1}$.

Nothing in this makes any mention of a co-product or requires it.